# Getting "Backend Error" once a day when loading data into BigQuery using the insertAll

Tags: google-bigquery

We are loading data every hour from a Postgres database into BigQuery using StreamSets Data Collector and utilizing the insertAll API. In general it works, but almost every morning (8 out of the last 10 days) the job that runs around 6:00AM Pacific fails with all of the rows for ~25 tables returned with a message "Backend Error". The total amount of data being loaded is about 150MB.

Is there any way to get more insight as to what would be causing these errors to throw during this time period? Are these Backend Errors considered "normal"?

This is using StreamSets Data Collector, so there isn't really any code to post. The stage sending in the rows is an HTTP Processor that uses `https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectid}/datasets/{dataset}/tables/{table}/insertAll`

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet which is generating that error? Also, what logs are indicating?

Comment: Can you provide more details how do you run your load job (if you are using Data Flow, Cloud Functions  ? In addition, just so I understand better, among all the load jobs during the day it just fails in the morning (6AM), right?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. No code to post since I am using a tool (StreamSets Data Collector)  to make the http requests. @AlexandreMoraes you are correct that the same job loads correctly throughout the whole day, once an hour, and fails around 6AM. This behavior happens in both our prod and dev environments, which have separate project IDs.

Comment: I understand. Can you share the full error message you receive?

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreMoraes, the way that our current StreamSets Data Collector pipeline is setup, we only get the response body containing "reason: backEnd Error" and the offending input row data, the latter of which containing data that I am unable to post here, but considering that the same information, with generally only a few changes to some rows, is sent 23 other times in the day without errors I am not sure how that can provide any additional usable information. Will see if I can make adjustments to get more specific information if you have access to dig into a specific job/request ID.

Comment: Have either of you run into this error before? If so, is the root issue generally on the client side, or have you found it to be a "network connection problem or a server overload" as stated here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages ?

Comment: I believe this might be a transient error or something related to your network connection specially at this time everyday. I do not see any issues because the job runs fine in the rest of the day.